# ssh dynamic port forwarding and tcpdump shows cleartext

Tags: dynamic, ssh, port, tcpdump, forwarding

I'm trying to encrypt my web traffic using SSH dynamic port forwarding in case I happen to be in multiple places such as internet cafes, hotels and so on.

On my laptop I installed an SSH server and executed:

```
ssh -C -D 1080 myuser@localost
```

I then configure my browser to use a socks proxy on localhost:1080

I tried to browse a few sites to see what was sent, but I guess
I'm doing clearly something wrong because upon a tcpdump:

```
sudo tcpdump -A -i eth0 dst www.example.com
```

I see everything in cleartext, even some fake password I tried 
on forms.

I thought I was setting up and encrypted tunnel, impossible to snoop.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Ok, moved it here: [link] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290267/ssh-dynamic-port-forwarding-and-tcpdump-shows-cleartext)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to people answering where I moved the question it turned out that the encrypted tunnel was actually created between localhost and localhost since I was running a  SSH server on localhost. Between localhost and example.com the http connection was not tunneled. So, of my needs, in case I happen to surf the web and want some privacy I should use an SSH server outside the network I'm in.